# Dates with deployed SSRS Reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have deployed 2 reports on the Development Report Server and the date parameters come up displayed in the american date format. When I deployed them on the report server on my pc it came up with the standard UK format. The 2 reports have has the language set on the report properties to EN-GB so I cant seem to work out why this is happening. Am I missing a setting that needs to be set up on the Server that the reporting services resides on ?

Comment: Hi James, have you tried to change the language property of the date field to US format?

Comment: Yes I changed it on the rdl to en-GB and it did not work. I want the date format as a british date.

Answer (score 0):

Your Development Report Server got global setup for OS as location = US - local PC have this setup for UK ( regional settings in control panel ).